# Get containing python class from element

Tags: python

Assuming I have a instance of class A (name it AI)
that has an instance of class B (name it BI).
Can a reference to BI (somewhere else) tell me that it is part of AI?

I don't talk about inheritance/parent class.

I know I can do this by implementing a reference to A
in the constructor of B - but can mighty Python do it for me?

Comment: An alternative to the answer below would be to  keep a list of instances of `A` and see if any of them have a reference to the instance of `B` you're interested in, if for some reason you can't add an attribute to `B`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> can mighty Python do it for me?

No, you have to do it yourself (by having every instance of B keep a reference to the corresponding instance of A).

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you mean?

```
class A(object):

    def __init__(self, BI):
        self.BI = BI
        self.BI.part_of = self

class B(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.part_of = None

BI = B()
AI = A(BI)

# BI.part_of is now AI
```

Comment: I thought BI would not be passed to A but is hardcoded in there. But using a variable in B holding A seems to be the solution. Thanks.